# Postgresql Array size limitation

Tags: arrays, postgresql, npgsql

When trying to insert an array of approximately 20kB in size it will not insert.
Specifically I can do an insert with multiple fields and 2 being arrays of 16kB and 20kB.  The insert will treat those fields as null or empty.  All other fields will have data stored except for the large arrays.
When I cut the array size to ~4kB it still does not insert.  At ~3kB it will insert.

I have tried using PG admin III with a manual query. 
My goal is to use npgsql.

I have tried `{1,2,3}` and `ARRAY[1,2,3]`.

My readings on the topic are that there are no limits on array size.  And that block size is the limit on all field sizes.

I am not concerned with performance.  This is being used for data storage more than querying.

```
INSERT INTO table (short_array, long_array) 
   VALUES ('{1,2,3}','{1,2,3...1,000}');

SELECT short_array FROM table;  //{1,2,3} 
SELECT long_array FROM table;   //
```

Comment: Can you prove that these arrays have not been inserted? Perhaps it is just pgAdmin failing to display them. Try with `psql`.

Comment: Thank you.  I checked by array element, and there is data. I also exported the data to confirm, and yes all data is present.  I thought by increasing characters per column in PG admin I would see the results.  I set it to max.  2147483647  and I have less than a million characters.  I should have assumed PG admin, because there was no error message on the insert.